# Wrapping Angular components which has Parent/Child relationship

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, components, parent-child

I'm trying to wrap some third-party components with my own components (All of them are Angular 5 components).

When using the third-party component (without wrapping them) I have the following code:

```
<div>
  <xyz-menubar>
    <a xyzMenubarItem></a>
    <a xyzMenubarItem></a>
  </xyz-menubar>
</div>
```

My goal is to wrap these components to have the following code:

```
<div>
  <app-menu>
    <app-menu-item></app-menu-item>
    <app-menu-item></app-menu-item>
  </app-menu>
</div>
```

This is how I coded the wrapped components (xyz-menubar wrapped into app-menu):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html'
})
export class MenuComponent {
}

<div>
  <xyz-menubar>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </xyz-menubar>
</div>
```

And xyzMenubarItem wrapped into app-menu-item:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-item',
  templateUrl: './menu-item.component.html'
})
export class MenuItemComponent {
}

<a xyzMenubarItem>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</a>
```

The main issue is that the 3rd party xyzMenubarItem component depends on xyzMenubar (its parent) as you can see below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'xyz-menubar-item, [xyzMenubarItem]',
  template: `
      <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class MenubarItemComponent {
  constructor(protected menubar: MenubarComponent, protected _elementRef?: ElementRef) {}
}
```

When trying to use my wrapped components (app-menu and app-menu-item as described in the beginning), I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[MenubarComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError[MenubarComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MenubarComponent!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:923)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10585)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:11806)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12302)
```

How should I wrap these 3rd party components that has child/parent dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workaround it by providing `MenuBarComponent` on you custom `app-menu` component:

```typescript
export function menuBarFactory(menu: MenuComponent) {
  return menu.menuBar;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  template: `
    <div>
      <xyz-menubar>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </xyz-menubar>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: MenuBarComponent, 
      useFactory: menuBarFactory,
      deps: [MenuComponent]
    }
  ]
})
export class MenuComponent {
  @ViewChild(MenuBarComponent) menuBar: MenuBarComponent;
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jaimvm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**